# Unable to get data from json server

Tags: json-server

I added a object called users in json server.,which can be accessed using http://localhost:3000/users.But when I try to log the data using Http in angular,I get error in console.

Can anyone help?

edit: I checked with jsonapi.typicode.com and that works

Following is the error:

```
Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: {…}, type: 3, url: null }

core.js:1673
defaultErrorLogger
core.js:1673
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError
core.js:1719
next
core.js:4319:109
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<
core.js:3555:34
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub
Subscriber.js:195
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next
Subscriber.js:133
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype._next
Subscriber.js:77
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype.next
Subscriber.js:54
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next
Subject.js:47
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.emit
core.js:3539:52
onHandleError/<
core.js:3846:48
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke
zone.js:388
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run
zone.js:138
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgZone.prototype.runOutsideAngular
core.js:3783
onHandleError
core.js:3846
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.handleError
zone.js:392
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runTask
zone.js:191
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneTask.invokeTask
zone.js:496
ZoneTask/this.invoke
zone.js:485
timer
```

Comment: What error? There is not really enough information to help with this question.

Comment: I have updated the error

Comment: The error is here, but the "logging code" is not, it is hard for me to help you without relevant code snippets.

Comment: For my case I was building the response from c# rest api got such an error using `return Ok(data);` in the controller; I changed that to return a **ResponseBody** with status code and response body. I am not sure about the theory behind the later working and the former not working so I am not in a position to give reason yet.